# How can I add an EC2 instance automatically to existing security group, elastic IP and VPC?

Tags: cloud, aws-cloudformation

I created new template `(*.json- see ettach)` for new instance from my images (AMIs).

How can I add the instance automatically to existing **security group, elastic ip and  VPC** ?

Thanks

```
{
"AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
"Description": "Ec2 block device mapping",
"Resources": {
    "MyEC2Instance": {
        "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
        "Properties": {
            "ImageId": "ami-1ff5111",
            "AvailabilityZone": "us-west-1a",
            "KeyName": "Test",
            "Tags": [{
                "Key": "Name",
                "Value": "RoiTest"
            }]
        }
    },
```

Comment: Please Help me Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The [Resource Types Reference section](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-template-resource-type-ref.html) of the [CloudFormation User Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/) is a good starting point to search for details such as the ones you're asking about. Specifically, you should check out the [AWS:EC2:Instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html) and the [AWS::EC2::EIPAssociation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-eip-association.html) references.

To associate an EC2 instance with a VPC security group you add the SecurityGroupIds property. To create the instance inside a VPC you actually have to define its subnet (which in turn is associated with a VPC), so you add the SubnetId property. And finally to associate an elastic IP to the instance you create an EIP association resource.

This is what your template will look like:

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  "Description": "Ec2 block device mapping",
  "Resources": {
    "MyEC2Instance": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
      "Properties": {
        "ImageId": "ami-1ff5111",
        "AvailabilityZone": "us-west-1a",
        "SubnetId": "<your existing subnet id here>",
        "SecurityGroupIds": [ "<your existing security group id here>" ],
        "KeyName": "Test",
        "Tags": [{
          "Key": "Name",
            "Value": "RoiTest"
        }]
      }
    },
    "MyEIPAssociation": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::EIPAssociation",
      "Properties": {
        "AllocationId": "<your existing elastic IP allocation id here>",
        "InstanceId": { "Ref": "MyEC2Instance" }
      }
    },
    ... (other resources in your template)
  }
}
```

It might be useful to point that the SecurityGroupIds property value is an array, so you can have an instance with multiple security groups.

Comment: Thank You! It works partially. Im still cannot associate the existing security groups prepared
Where to write this  in the code?

Comment: If you're creating your EC2 instance inside a VPC, it can only be associated with security groups in the same VPC. Are you sure that your existing security group is a VPC security group and that it is associated with the same VPC in which you're creating the EC2 instance?

Comment: First, Thank you. I dont  created ec2 instance to vpc. how can i do it?, whare i need to wirte in my json template? of course i need also securuity group. for now' if i started my template i haved new instance but not  associated to any vpc' security groups. Please Help me :)